# How to combine Bump Maps?

Tags: uv, node-editor

I'm trying to add a bump map with logo to noise texture Bump map.

I have a bump map created with *Noise texture* and then on top of that I want to add my bump logo (which also has it's own color on it.)

Is it possible within one material?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One way is to use 'daisy chaining' through the *Normal input*.

*Daisy chaining bump maps.*
[image]

*Adding a different material to each part.*
[image]

Comment: It is not a fully problem solve, but thank You very much for example.

Comment: You've mixed two bump maps, but now Im trying to add texture as a UV map to certain face on my object (logo like Hell Yes!) and make it look silver metalic. Should I just create another image texture and add it as base color? But then I will lose my base metalic black color.
I mean Now we have a dent logo and bump from noise texture and all of this should be on a black metalic color. Now I want to make that dented logo area metalic silver inside :D

Comment: Thanks. I wish Icould figure this out by myself. Propably I should just buy Substance Painter or use Mixer.