# How do I mix two bump nodes and fade from one to the other?

Tags: texturing, node-editor, bump

Here is a simple flower bud with a colour pattern using noise and a gradient texture.

[image]

Now I want to add two textures, a wave pattern for the petals and a noise pattern for the stem. I have used a gradient into a colour ramp as a kind of mask. The texture settings are set high here just so it's easy to see. Each bump node I have run into the normal input on a diffuse shader (I think the problem is here). Because when I then mix it with the base colour pattern I'm getting the colour data from the diffuse nodes blending with the base colour pattern in the first image.

[image]

[image]

How can I add these two texture/bump nodes and fade between them in a way that doesn't interfere with the base colour pattern I want to use?

EDIT: This question was closed as a duplicate, but the linked question is a different issue. I was able to solve this problem by dragging the colour output from the colour ramp node for the pattern into the diffuse bsdf nodes for each texture. It feels like a messy set-up to me, I think this could be done more elegantly.

[image]

Comment: Hi @JachymMichal thank you. That is close. But it doesn't solve the problem of fading one texture into the other. It uniformly applies them together...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your chosen route is to mix two shaders, each shader with its own normals, generated from heights, using Bump nodes.

Mixing Shaders is, as far as I know, gathering contributions from each shader, biasing samples made by the renderer, in Cycles. In EEVEE, I'm not sure.  In particular, I don't know how normals are combined. Maybe someone who knows can help with that. Mixing normals is [tricky](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/38298/35559): they represent directions; just mixing the colors that encode the directions won't do.

Why the ramble? Because, however that's done, mixing *heights* is easy by comparision. It's just an addition.

Personally, using the 'Node Wrangler' shipped-add-on's convenience, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd>-clicking nodes to preview their output as I went along, I would ..

[image]

- Preview the *Wave* and *Noise* textures, and try them out through Bump on their own, on a neutral material. I would put whatever was needed around them (perhaps *Color Ramp / Multiply*) to adjust the heights, *before* they get to  the *Bump* node.
- Preview the Gradient, on its own, to make sure it was oriented correctly, and roughly right.

So the resulting chunk of tree would be something like this:

[image]

What's in those 'Adjusted' groups will depend on how you want your waves and noise to look. The *Multiply Add*  is just my choice for changing the width and location of the gradient.

The only suggestion is that it's easier to mix heights, here, than shaders, or normals.

Comment: Thank you that's a helpful answer. It looks like I've stumbled into a rabbit hole here re: combining normals, the linked answer and subsequent links there, are informative and dense. The [originally linked](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/174580/how-to-combine-bump-maps) suggested duplicate answer was succinct solution to this and useful but didn't help me with mixing the gradient transition in.