# combining bump node issue

Tags: shader-nodes, bump

I am trying to combine the result of two black and white node based textures to use it as a bump map (by pluging the black and white texture on the height input of the bump map node) but only result having this weird broken result:[image]

Here is my first bump map:[image]

Here is the second bump map[image]

Here the black and white texture when mixing the two separate textures:[image]

When connecting this black and white map to a bump map node I get this:[image]

but when connecting the bump node to the principal BSDF it is all broken:[image]

I try different ways to connects the nodes as seen in this topic ([How to combine Bump Maps?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/174580/how-to-combine-bump-maps))[image]

but get the same broken result.

Any idea why this happens and how to fix it ?

I have made a small scale test with two texture and it worked fine:[image] so something in the node system must be messing with the end result:[image]

Here is the blend file:
[image]

Comment: I can't reproduce your issue, connected the mixed color to the bump like so: https://i.imgur.com/quzD7QH.png and got this: https://i.imgur.com/uxgOdxy.png maybe it's a bug or hardware issue?

Comment: @MarkusvonBroady what version of blender did you use ? Are you using a Mac or a PC ?
I used the 2.92.0 with a macbook

Comment: 3.0 Windows PC, but I think it matters less what I use.

Comment: After testing on other device all Windows it seems it is linked to my mac